# Alias template, partial specialization and the invalid parameter type void

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, void, template-aliases

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename F>
struct S;

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct S<Ret(Args...)> { };

template<typename... Args>
using Alias = S<void(Args...)>;

int main() {
    S<void(int)> s;
    Alias<int> alias;
}
```

It works fine, as expected and both the line involving `S` and the one involving `Alias` define under the hood the same type `S<void(int)>`.

Now, consider the following changes:

```
int main() {
    S<void(void)> s;  // this line compiles
    Alias<void> alias;  // this line does not
}
```

I expected it to compile, for reasons that are similar to the ones above mentioned.
It goes without saying that it doesn't compile because of the line involving `Alias`, instead I get the error:

> In substitution of 'template using Alias = S [with Args = {void}]'
>
> [...]
>
> error: invalid parameter type 'void'

The question is pretty simple: what I missed here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [dcl.fct], emphasis mine:

> A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of **non-dependent** type `void` is equivalent to an empty parameter list. Except for this special case, a parameter shall not have type *cv* `void`.

In this case, `Args...` is a dependent type pack, so `void` is not allowed there. This idea is repeated in a note in [temp.deduct]:

> *[ Note:* Type deduction may fail for the following reasons:
>   — [...]
>   — Attempting to create a function type in which a parameter has a type of `void`, or in which the return
>   type is a function type or array type.
>   — [...]
>   *—end note ]*

Note that `S<void(void)>` compiles since `void(void)` is non-dependent and is equivalent to `void()`, so `Ret(Args...)` is never deduced to have `void` in the parameter list - it's deduced with `Args...` empty.

---

At least there's a simple workaround in that you can just write `Alias<>`.

Comment: The workaround is obvious, but shouldn't it fail compiling both the lines for the same reason? Also `S<void(void)>` leads to a deduction that is attempting (well, succeeding) to *create a function type in which a parameter has a type of `void`*. Am I wrong?

Comment: @skypjack Just found the section I was looking for. The `void` has to be non-dependent.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Anyway, isn't also `Args` in `template<typename Ret, typename... Args> struct S<Ret(Args...)> { };` a dependent type that should suffer from the same problem?

Comment: @skypjack There I think you're fine since you're passing in `void(void)` explicitly. Not 100% sure, by any stretch

Comment: You know, I'm creating a new question for that, so start looking around for the right part of the reference!! :-)

Comment: @skypjack Updated to clarify why `void(void)` works.

Comment: Thank you!! I've also opened a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35885199/4987285) for that, if you want to participate it would be great. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use `Alias<>` in my real problem, because it's more complex that this one, but I'm creating a new question maybe for it.