# Dependent type pack deduction fails when using void... When and why?

Tags: c++, c++11, void, type-deduction, template-aliases

This question is a follow-up of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879510/alias-template-partial-specialization-and-the-invalid-parameter-type-void).
Consider the following code:

```
template<typename F>
struct S;

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct S<Ret(Args...)> { };

template<typename... Args>
using Alias = S<void(Args...)>;

int main() {
    S<void(void)> s; // (1)
    Alias<void> alias; // (2)
}
```

If we comment out *(2)*, the example complies, otherwise the compilation fails.
From the linked question we find that *(2)* fails because:

> A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of non-dependent type void is equivalent to an empty parameter list. Except for this special case, a parameter shall not have typecv void.

Moreover:

> [ Note: Type deduction may fail for the following reasons:
>   — [...]
>   — Attempting to create a function type in which a parameter has a type of void, or in which the return type is a function type or array type.
>   — [...]
>   —end note ]

What's not clear to me is why *(1)* compiles.

In other terms, if *(2)* fails because `Args` is a dependent type and suffers from the above mentioned limitation in:

```
template<typename... Args>
using Alias = S<void(Args...)>;
```

The same problem should affect `Args` in:

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct S<Ret(Args...)> { };
```

Why is it fine using `void` as `S<void(void)>` in this case?
Note that the rush is towards the `std::function` that accepts as well this kind of signature.

Comment: `S<void(void)>` is equivalent to `S<void()>` and deduces `Args` to be an empty pack. That is to say, the *type-id*s `void(void)` and `void()` name the exact same type.

Comment: That what I guessed, but the alias and the structure should behave almost the same, because `Alias<void>` ends with `S<void(void)>`. Right?

Comment: No, because `Args` in `Alias` is dependent.

Comment: @T.C. Also `Args` in `template<typename Ret, typename... Args> struct S<Ret(Args...)> { };` is dependent, am I wrong? It's a template parameter, but I'm not sure if those parameters must be considered dependent types when dealing with specializations.

Comment: `Args` in `S<Ret(Args...)>` is deduced, not specified, and it's deduced against `void()`, which is the function type that the *type-id* `void(void)` names.

Comment: @T.C. Ok, got the reason behind that now, it's due to the fact that it is deduced because of part of a specialization. If you put the comment in an answer, I'll accept it to close the question.